# extend abstract class and get its getter values using spring wiring

Tags: java, spring

consider the following code:

```
public abstract class MachineInPitImpl extends AbstractPersistentObject implements MachineInPit {

 protected PersonReference currentOperatorRef;
 public void setCurrentOperatorRef(PersonReference currentOperatorRef) {
    this.currentOperatorRef = currentOperatorRef;
    this.currentOperatorObj = null;
}
public PersonReference getCurrentOperatorRef() {
    return currentOperatorRef;
}
```

The above class is not wired with spring context, I need to extend this class and grab the values in the get method of this class in my new class.
I have wrote a class as this:

```
public class MachineOPJMXBeanImpl extends MachineInPitImpl {
public MachineOPJMXBeanImpl(){

}

@Override
public PersonReference getCurrentOperatorRef() {
    return super.getCurrentOperatorRef();
}
}
```

But the value in this class get method is null.Why am I getting null value?
Here is the applicationcontext.xml file:

```
<bean id="machineOPJMXBean"
      class="com.mincom.works.cc.personnel.node.MachineOPJMXBeanImpl" parent="machineInPitImpl">
    <property name="currentOperatorRef" ref="currentOperatorRef"/>

</bean>

<bean id="machineInPitImpl" class="minestar.pitlink.domain.pitmodel.MachineInPitImpl" abstract="true" scope="singleton" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="currentOperatorRef" ref="currentOperatorRef"/>


</bean>

<bean id="currentOperatorRef" class="minestar.machinetracking.domain.PersonReference"/>
```

Comment: Show the code where you're calling `getCurrentOperatorRef`.

Comment: @chrylis The `getCurrentOperatorref` is called in `machineinpitimpl` class which is shown above. I have debugged this class and checked the values is there in this method. But when I call from `MachineOPJMXBeanimpl` class with super word its giving null value.

Comment: Where's the *client* code that's calling it?

Comment: @chrylis The full code I cannot manage to paste chrylis for security reasons. Just assume that the value is there in `machineinpitimpl` .

Comment: Then there's not enough information to help you, though I recommend you look here for one possible issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null

Comment: Is minestar.machinetracking.domain.PersonReference a BeanFactory?

Comment: @andresoviedo It is a java class.

Comment: @chrylis Hi, I think when my spring xml instantiates the `machineinpitimpl` class it running only the init method which is in the default constructor. How can I have a another constructor so that it instantiates the whole class?

Comment: @lifeatstake Seeing your example, the injection should be working fine. Can you send the piece of code where you are instantiating the context and getting your "machineOPJMXBean" bean?

Comment: @andresoviedo Check my comment to chrylis. Can this be a reason. 
And the xml code is pasted above. Do you need something more?

Comment: @lifeatstake Are you getting your bean like "appContext.getBean("machineOPJMXBean");

Comment: @andresoviedo No. It's a 13 gb code. The code to get the bean is wired previously.

Comment: @lifeatstake My suspicion is that your "machineOPJMXBean" is not being constructed by Spring.  Can't help more without more info.  I would suggest to isolate your test in a JUnit and verify that property is being injected correctly.

Comment: @andresoviedo What does this do then:
`<bean id="machineOPJMXBean"
      class="com.mincom.works.cc.personnel.node.MachineOPJMXBeanImpl" parent="machineInPitImpl">
    <property name="currentOperatorRef" ref="currentOperatorRef"/>

</bean>`

Comment: @chrylis How will I instantiate a named constructor. The constructor is like this `public MachineInPitImpl(MachineInPitImpl mip){//here are the attributes initialised}` . How will I give this constructor as constructor-args in spring.